# How to solve linear recurrence relation based on conditions?

Tags: recurrence-relations, matrix-exponential, programming

Given

$F(n)=a\cdot F(n-1)-b$ ,$n$ even

$F(n)=a\cdot F(n-1)+b$ ,$n$ odd

$F(0),a,b$ are constants.

How to calculate $n$-th term in $log(n)$ time?

I learnt matrix exponentiation technique.
But problem is that the transformation matrix changes in each step

Can it be used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write F(n) in terms of F(n-2) 
separately for even and odd n.

For even n,
$F(n) = a F(n-1)-b = a(aF(n-2)+b)-b
=a^2F(n-2)+ab-b
$
and similarly for odd n.

Then treat even and odd n F
as independent sequences.

(added later)

Letting $g(n) = F(2n)$
and
$h(n) = F(2n-1)$,
the recurrences are

$F(2n) =a^2F(2n-2)+ab-b
$
so
$g(n) = a^2g(n-1)+ab-b
$
and,
for odd n,
$F(n) = a F(n-1)+b = a(aF(n-2)-b)-b
=a^2F(n-2)-ab+b
$
so
$F(2n+1) 
=a^2F(2n-1)-ab+b
$
so
$h(n) = a^2h(n-1)-ab+b
$.

Both of these
are of the form
$r(n) = ur(n-1)+v
$.

I like to solve them 
by turning them into
a telescoping sum
this way.

If $u = 1$
then it is
$r(n) = r(n-1)+v
$
so
$r(n) = nv+r(0)$.
Otherwise
divide by $u^n$ to get
$\dfrac{r(n)}{u^n}
=\dfrac{r(n-1)}{u^{n-1}}+\dfrac{v}{u^n}
$
or
$\dfrac{r(n)}{u^n}-\dfrac{r(n-1)}{u^{n-1}}
=\dfrac{v}{u^n}
$.

This telescopes nicely
and we get

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{r(m)}{u^m}-r(0)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}(\dfrac{r(n)}{u^n}-\dfrac{r(n-1)}{u^{n-1}})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\dfrac{v}{u^n}\\
&=\dfrac{v}{u^m}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}u^{m-n}\\
&=\dfrac{v}{u^m}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}u^{n}\\
&=\dfrac{v}{u^m}\dfrac{u-u^m}{1-u}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$r(m)
= r(0) u^m+v\dfrac{u-u^m}{1-u}
$.

If $u < 1$
then
$r(m) 
\to \dfrac{vu}{1-u}
$;
if $u > 1$
then

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{r(m)}{u^m}
&= r(0) +v(\dfrac{u^{-m+1}}{1-u}-\dfrac{1}{1-u})\\
&\to r(0) -\dfrac{v}{1-u}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is nothing but $F(n)=aF(n-1)+(-1)^{n+1}b.$ If $a=0,$ you have the solution for the recurrence. Otherwise note that $$\dfrac{F(n)}{a^n}-\dfrac{F(n-1)}{a^{n-1}}=\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}b}{a^n}$$ and [telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series#In_general). For the series in RHS you can use the geometric series formula.